# Create a file with DownloadsFolder and show it in file explorer

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to create a file using `DownloadsFolder` and then I want to show it in user file explorer. I know I can use `Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync` to do so, but it requires a `StorageFolder` as argument, but I'm quite sure there's no way to get one for that specific directory.

How should I do then?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access DownloadsFolder but here's a trick I used in my apps.

First you have to create a file type association in package.appxmanifest in your app.
Second you need create a folder inside Downloads folder and add this folder to StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList with a token name.
so:

```
public async Task CreatePictureFolderAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var folder = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Pictures");
        // add your folder to StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList
        StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace(token, folder);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ex.Exception("CreatePictureFolderAsync"); }
}
```

now for creating a file do this>

```
string token = "picturesTokenNaME";
private async void btnCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await CreatePictureFolderAsync();
        var folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(token);
        var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("abc.txt", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "ameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");

    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ex.Exception("btnCreate_Click"); }
}
```

so to open this folder, just do this:

```
 private async void btnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(token);
            var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("abc.txt");
            var text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            Debug.WriteLine(text);
            await Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync(folder);
        }
```

hope this help you.

Ramtin.